# How to send function with value to child component React?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, components, parent-child

Actually in my React native App i have a problem sending a id value from a Parent view to a child component in the **Logout** function, i don't knon how send the value into the function; actually i have the next console errors:

*Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.*
**And**
*TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'users.current.id')*

My resum code is the next (Home is parent, GeneralHeader is child):

**Home.tsx** (*I can see printed the correct string value (users.current.id) in console*)

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, Container, Content, View} from 'native-base'
import Styles from './Styles/HomeStyles'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import GeneralHeader from '../Components/GeneralHeader'
import {Auth} from '../Services/Auth/AuthService'

const Home =(props) => {
   const {navigation, users} = props;

   return(
    <Container >
        {console.log(users.current.id)}
        <GeneralHeader backButton={false} moreButton={true} title={"Home"} logoutFunc={Logout(users.current.id)}/>
        <Content >      
            <View style={Styles.content}>                  
                <Text>Hola {users.current.id}</Text>
            </View>
        </Content>
     </Container>
    );

  async function Logout(id:string){
    await Auth.LogoutUser(id, props);
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
  const {users} = state;
  return {users};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

**GeneralHeader.tsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Button, Header, Body, Title, Left, Right, Icon, Card, CardItem, Text, Fab} from 'native-base'


const GeneralHeader=(props)=>{
    const {backButton, title, moreButton, logoutFunc} = props;
    return(
     <>
        <Header>
            {
                backButton===true ? 
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                :null
            }              
            <Body>
                <Title>{title}</Title>
            </Body>
            {
                moreButton===true? 
                <Right>
                    <Button transparent onPress={()=> logoutFunc}>
                        <Icon name='menu' />
                    </Button>        
                </Right>
                :null
            }
        </Header>
     </>
    );
 }

 export default GeneralHeader;
```

Comment: Just simply change `logoutFunc={Logout(users.current.id)}` into `logoutFunc={()=>Logout(users.current.id)}`. When use bare `Logout(users.current.id)` the function will execute rightaway during component render

Comment: that way render but then it does nothing when i press the button

Comment: In your Button component, you should call the function instead of return the function itself. change `onPress={()=> logoutFunc}` to `onPress={()=> logoutFunc()}`. That will do

Comment: It works, the function is called; i have to fix an error with Navigator but your comment is correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const Logout = (id:string)=>async ()=>{
    await Auth.LogoutUser(id, props);
    navigation.navigate('Login');
}

<Button transparent onPress={logoutFunc}>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, now it marks a new error "TypeError: Logout is not a function. (In 'Logout(users.current.id)', 'Logout' is undefined)"

Answer (score 0):

#### edited

I've never used react native, but i've tried with react.
Idk why would you want to do this but if you want to handle this beahaviour i would recommend to use a function that returns a function... something like:

> If ECMA script 6 syntax is allowed:

```js
const handleLogout = (id:string) => async () => {
  await Auth.LogoutUser(id, props);
  navigation.navigate('Login');
};
...
```

**Home.tsx** remains the same

```
<GeneralHeader backButton={false} moreButton={true} title={"Home"} logoutFunc={handleLogout(users.current.id)}/>
```

**GeneralHeader.tsx** changes to

```
<Button transparent onPress={logoutFunc}>
  <Icon name='menu' />
</Button>
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: TypeError: Logout is not a function. (In 'Logout(users.current.id)', 'Logout' is undefined). And i change handleLogout name const by Logout

Comment: Sorry i missed sonthing it wasnt `Logout` it is `handleLogout(users.current.id)` in your **Home.tsx -> General header** , that will do the work

Comment: In another comment somebody put the solution, to change in the button:                                                    
   onPress={()=> logoutFunc} to onPress={()=> logoutFunc()}

Comment: That works too, but is more react like syntax in this way `consta logountFunc = () => () => {...}` it all depends in how you want to handle it :), greetings!